# Reference variables alias in c++

Tags: c++

I am new in coding  Please explain this code. I didn't get this logic.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

void main()
{
     int a = 32, *p = &a;
     char c ='A', &ch = c; 
     ch += a; 
     *p += c; 
     cout << "\n" << a << " " << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us what exactly you don't get. We can just repeat a classical explanation from some book, but this is no better than you reading it yourself.

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Yaa, ok I will use int . But did'nt get what will be the output .

Answer (score 0):

Since `p` is the location of `a`, `*p` – the `int` at that location – is the same `int` as `a`.
Similarly, since `ch` is a reference to `c`, `ch` is the same `char` as `c`.

Thus, what you have is equivalent to (after fixing the typos)

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a = 32;
    char c ='A'; 
    c += a; 
    a += c;
    std::cout << "\n" << a << " " << c << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: what will be the exact output.

Comment: Compile and run the program and see.